# Callback from java script to C# ,Asynchronous programming between c# and java script

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, asynchronous

I have a silver-light based web application.I am using ScriptObject to connect and call method in java script and in turn java script interact with plugin. All the function call from c# to java script was synchronous.now Now I am trying to use web socket server for replacement for plugin.

Now I am just changing the code of the  methods in java script file to interact with web socket server.
Since web Socket call are asynchronous in nature I am not able to implement the call from c# to java script and return value.

Now I wanted call callback from java script to c# code.Is this is possible ?

Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Comment: And you did consider SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

You annotate a class like this:

```
public class MyScriptableManagedType {
        [ScriptableMember()]
        public string MyToUpper(string str) {
            return str.ToUpper();
        }

        [ScriptableMember()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

put it in the page's scope of javascript objects:

```
MyScriptableManagedType smt = new MyScriptableManagedType();

HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("mySLapp", smt);
```

Then you can use it from javascript like so:

```
var slCtl = null;
function pluginLoaded(sender,args){
     slCtl  = sender.getHost();
     alert(slCtl.Content.mySLapp.MyToUpper("Test String"));
}
```

The function pluginLoaded has to be registered with the silverlight plugin to be called on load.

Take from and more details at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414(v=vs.95).aspx